# sw-precache StripPrefixMulti option

Tags: javascript, service-worker, sw-precache

I'm trying to remove two prefixes from my service-worker file but the stripPrefixMulti option doesn't seem to do the trick.
I have :

```
./dist
./src/assets
```

I want to strip :

```
./
src/
```

and replace them with

```
/
```

So in my sw.config I have :

```
stripPrefix : './',  // tried moving this to PrefixMulti as 'root': './'
stripPrefixMulti: {
  'src/': 'src/'
},
replacePrefix: '/'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't your stripPrefixMulti look like `{ 'src/' : '' }` ? Maybe you can also post your grunt / gulp task and the whole sw-precache config. And explain how your file structure looks like before the build and how it should look like after the build.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you.